# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^{2k} e^{i(n-a)x}\, dx\right|$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Study the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^{2k} e^{i(n-a)x}\, dx\right|$$
for $k\in\mathbb N$ and $a\in\mathbb R$, $a\notin\mathbb N$.

My attempt.I have applied the comparison test for series, but doing so
$$\left|\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^{2k} e^{i(n-a)x}\, dx\right|\leq 2 \int_{0}^\pi x^{2k} dx$$
the dependence on $n$ disappears and we can not conclude anything.

Any suggestions please?